# php curl - allow calls with expired certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

Using curl to make calls to the server. The connection is made on the protocol https using ssl certificate.

Use the following code.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $szUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $this->aConfig['certificatePath']);
```

I realized that despite the certificate has expired curl continues to function properly. why? no way to verify the certificate has expired?

what safety problems exposes this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Support for:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
```

removed with cURL 7.28.1.

Use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Should do the trick.